# Combination of elements in an array returning sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11

I am learning optimization problem using data structures.

For that I have considered a problem in hand.

I have an array like:  `movies[] = { 2,3,4,5,6,7,2,4,9 }`

I have a sum value: `k = 5`

Now I am finding the combination of array elements returning the `"k"`
For example:

```
2 + 3 = 5
3 + 2 = 5
```

The code below is able to do that:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>
using namespace std;

std::tuple<int, int> movies_combo(int k,int movies[]) {
    int value_1 = 0, value_2 = 0;
    int size = sizeof(movies);

    //First lets sort the array in ascending order
    //For optimized solution
    double mid = sizeof(movies) / 2;

    //Second lets find the sum of combination of array elements which gives "k"
    for (int i = 0; i < (size-1); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (size - 1); j++) {
            if (movies[i] + movies[j] == k) {

                cout << "The two movies are: " << movies[i] << "and" << movies[j] << endl;

            }
        }
    }
    return make_tuple(value_1, value_2);
}

int main() {
    int movies[] = { 2,3,4,5,6,7,2,4,9 };
    int k = 6;
    int value_1, value_2;

    tie(value_1,value_2) = movies_combo(k, movies);

    //cout << "The two movies are: " << value_1 << "and" << value_2 << endl;
}
```

Now I have the time complexity of O(n^2).

I can reduce the complexity further by sorting the array in the beginning and eliminating the values > k. But this is useful only in couple of scenarios and not the general solution of optimization.

I am hoping that there are data structures and algorithmic methods which can be very handy in this case to bring down the complexity of logarithmic level example: nlogn or logn.

If someone has got any idea on reducing the time complexity then let me know.

Comment: If your code works fine, and you are only seeking to improve it: your question is out of scope of SO, and is better asked on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius...I did not know about codereview section of SE. Thanks I will move this there.

Comment: Use a set data structure. Loop through the elements, and then test if `k-n` is in the set.

Comment: @Barmar...Awesome...thanks..I think that improves a lot.

Comment: This is also known as "2-SUM". I would give some links, but there are so many.

Comment: @KennyOstrom...Please post them here...I would like to learn them.

Comment: @statisticalbeginner -- 1) This can be done in `O(n)`.  2) This does not work the way you think it does -- `int size = sizeof(movies);`  -- Arrays decay to pointers when passed, and in that line you're asking for the `sizeof(int *)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in time **O(nlogn)** and even better **O(n)**.

**O(nlogn)** approach:

**1**.Sort the elements in time **O(nlogn)** time.

**2**.For each element `movies[i]`, apply **[binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)** in array from position `i+1` till end of the array to search element `k - movies[i]`.

**3**.If found, you have your tuple since `movies[i] + (k - movies[i]) = k`

**O(n)** approach:

**1**.Store all the elements in a hashtable.

**2**.For each element `movies[i]`, search `k - movies[i]` in hashtable, if found you have your tuple.

**3**.Since search in hashtable takes **O(1)** time, this approach takes time **O(n)**.